# Need Python script to render a Mantaflow domain (randomly accessed) sequence in an externally specified order from a defined camera path

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, file-format

I have a working animated Blender file that contains a Mantaflow domain and a camera path. The domain contains 15 states stored in a cache directory and the camera path (Bezier curve) has 180 positions (time frames) with associated camera positions and rotations. The problem I have is that I need to be able to render an arbitrarily specified Mantaflow domain configuration (1 of the 15) for each of the 180 frames (camera positions and rotations). I'm struggling with the Python code; I've never programmed in a Blender environment before. I'm working with Windows files and directory formats in Blender 2.90.1 with the cycles render engine.

Would a viable solution be to access an external file, 180 elements long matched to each camera position/rotation, with each element being an index to one of the 15 Mantaflow configurations and then generate a render for each 180 camera vectors? I obviously I don't understand the intricacies of Mantaflow and I haven't been successful in doing a random access of the cache. I have all the elements of the scene and camera specified as I need them in the Blender file, otherwise. Should I start by looping through the time steps and write out the camera vectors to an external file? Then, how would I go about setting a specified order for the Mantaflow object?

Would some kind soul suggest a (better) way to do this and provide coding for a solution? I would be very grateful for any guidance.